# Passing an equals sign to a macro in SAS

Tags: parameters, macros, sas, call, execute

I'm trying to generate code in a data step, and then pass the code into a macro which then runs the code. It's a bit roundabout, I know, but I can't think of a better solution, since the contents of my code are based on what's in the dataset.

In my dataset, "test2", I have only one observation of the variable "statement", which is equal to

> j1=input(j,anydtdtm.); drop j; rename j1=j; k1=input(k,anydtdtm.); drop k; rename k1=k; l1=input(l,anydtdtm.); drop l; rename l1=l;

I have a macro which is basically

```
%macro dummy(ds,statements);
    data &ds.2;
        set &ds.;    
        &statements.
    run;
%mend;
```

then I use call execute to the following:

```
data test3;
    set test2;
    call execute('%dummy('||strip(ds)||','||strip(statement)||')');
run;
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The keyword parameter J1 was not defined with the macro.
```

Clearly SAS is interpreting my "=" sign as something other than the contents of a macro variable. I tried using %str and altering my call execute to:

```
data test3;
    set test2;
    call execute('%dummy('||strip(ds)||','||%str(strip(statement))||')');
run;
```

but it didn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to automate conversion of types? An array within a data step may be better, with a dynamic rename statement? If you pass the variable names alone and have a system the macro should generate the rest of the code.

Comment: I am automating conversion, but I have to run through the whole dataset before determining which variables to convert

Comment: @JonathanWilson You're looking at what I would call a 'solved problem', insomuch as a lot of us have had the same problem.  If you'd like suggestions for how you could do it less roundabout-ly, post another question with some more details about what you're actually doing - what does it look like _before_ you get to the one variable above.  What ends up being used to populate that.  There are myriad ways to approach this; yours is not a bad one, but there are better, and I for one would be happy to give mine (and I'm sure others would be too).

Comment: Do leave this one, though, as is; it's a good example of macro quoting and a few ways to get around it.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the tip! It hadn't really occurred to me to ask all of your thoughts on the issue of "how", but that would be really cool! I'll post another question

Comment: Also noticed a typo in my original question. the call exectue should have %dummy instead of %convert. edited it

Comment: @Joe OK I posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777135/automating-readins-in-sas-to-avoid-truncation-and-properly-classify-numeric-vari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you use named parameters, this isn't a problem.

```
%macro dummy(ds=,statements=);
    data &ds.2;
        set &ds.;    
        &statements.
    run;
%mend;


data class;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

data fixes;
  infile datalines truncover;
  length statement $40 all_statements $512 execstr $1024;
  do _n_ = 1 to 2;
      input @1 statement $40.;
      all_statements=catx(';',all_statements,statement);
  end;
  put all_statements;
  execstr = cats('%dummy(ds=class,statements=',all_statements,';)');
  call execute(execstr);
  datalines;
if sex='M' then m_height=height
if sex='F' then f_height=height
;;;;
run;
```

Then SAS sees the named-parameter equal sign and knows that everything from that to the next comma is the value of that parameter.

Of course, if you have a comma, you still need to do something.  Here is where you were close-but-not-quite.  `%str` needs to be quoting the *macro call*, not the *construction* of the macro call - in other words, it needs to be inside the quotes.

```
data fixes;
  infile datalines truncover;
  length statement $40 all_statements $512 execstr $1024;
  do _n_ = 1 to 2;
      input @1 statement $40.;
      all_statements=catx(';',all_statements,statement);
  end;
  put all_statements;
  execstr = cats('%dummy(ds=class,statements=%nrstr(',all_statements,';))');
  call execute(execstr);
  datalines;
if sex in ('M','F') then mfheight=height
if sex='F' then f_height=height
;;;;
run;
```

Personally I like `%nrstr` here since it also eliminates those pesky ampersands and percent signs, which might have some meaning.

Putting it there means that when SAS runs that call execute, it passes along that `%str` or `%nrstr` and quotes the value that is being sent on.

When you had it in the other place:

```
execstr = cats('%dummy(ds=class,statements=',%nrstr(all_statements),';)');
```

What was being protected/quoted was not the text inside `all_statements` but actually the characters `all_statements` (in other words, the *variable name*).  That doesn't really do much for you.

Comment: Not sure what creating named parameters has to do with this problem. You can call a macro using the parameter names, even for parameters that are defined as positional.  `%macro dummy(statement)... %dummy(statement=...)`

Comment: True, but I tend to follow one or the other consistently. I suppose this might be an example of when hybrid makes sense.

Comment: @Joe I don't think I really understand what exactly is going on re: the difference between using named and positional parameters (is that the correct way to refer to them? Is named with the = sign and positional without?). Anyway, I took your solution and I think I improved on it a bit. Can you take a look at my solution and comment on whether or not it makes sense?

Comment: @JonathanWilson Named parameters with equal sign, yes - means when you call the macro you have to use them by name (`%macro_name(param1=A, param2=B)`) but you can put them in any order, versus positional parameters where you leave off the equal sign and it assigns parameters by position (`%macro_name(A,B)`).  Tom is right that the user can still use the `param1=A` method even if positional is specified.

Comment: OK, I understand what's going on now. It took me a second, but I changed it to named parameters and added "ds=" and "statements=" to my call execute and it solved everything

Answer (score 4):

Passing an equal sign is easy, just use named parameters in the call.

```
%dummy(ds=x,statement=x=2)
```

It is passing the semi-colons that is really hard. For that you will need to quote the values in the macro call. You can do it with macro quoting, but I find it is easier to use normal quotes and remove them in the macro code.

Have the macro remove any quotes that might surround the parameter value by using the `DEQUOTE()` function.

```
%macro dummy(ds,statements);
data &ds.2;
  set &ds.;    
  %sysfunc(dequote(&statements))
run;
%mend;
```

Let's setup your example statements as a dataset.

```
data have;
  ds='x';
  statements=
   'j1=input(j,anydtdtm.); drop j; rename j1=j;'
|| 'k1=input(k,anydtdtm.); drop k; rename k1=k;'
|| 'l1=input(l,anydtdtm.); drop l; rename l1=l;'
  ;
run;
```

And some sample data for those statements to operate on.

```
data x;
 j='01JAN1960';
 k='10FEB2010';
 l='2014-05-01';
run;
```

Now you can generate the call using your data set. Use the `QUOTE()` function to enclose the statements in quotes.

```
options mprint;
data _null_;
  set have ;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%dummy)(',ds,',',quote(trim(statements)),')'));
run;
```

Here is the LOG.

```
1    + %dummy(x,"j1=input(j,anydtdtm.); drop j; rename j1=j;k1=input(k,anydtdtm.); drop k; rename
k1=k;l1=input(l,anydtdtm.); drop l; rename l1=l;")
MPRINT(DUMMY):   data x2;
MPRINT(DUMMY):   set x;
MPRINT(DUMMY):   j1=input(j,anydtdtm.);
MPRINT(DUMMY):   drop j;
MPRINT(DUMMY):   rename j1=j;
MPRINT(DUMMY):  k1=input(k,anydtdtm.);
MPRINT(DUMMY):   drop k;
MPRINT(DUMMY):   rename k1=k;
MPRINT(DUMMY):  l1=input(l,anydtdtm.);
MPRINT(DUMMY):   drop l;
MPRINT(DUMMY):   rename l1=l;
MPRINT(DUMMY):   run;
```

Comment: I feel like this does solve the problem, but it's a messy way, don't you think?  Using data step quoting to solve a macro quoting problem?

Comment: Because regular quotes are easier to generate than macro quotes, even in macro code, but especially inside of a data step.  The macro as defined will work fine if the user passes in statements that are only macro quoted as the `DEQUOTE()` function will do nothing to values that are not quoted.

Comment: I'm not sure one is easier than the other here, is it?  Except macro quoting avoids needing `dequote()`?

Comment: Why is `dequote()` harder than `%unquote()`?  Also do not need to worry about % or parens in the value being quoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the cases where it may be easier to generate the code in a file, and then submit it with an %include statement:

```
filename tempsas temp;
data test3;
  set test2;
  file tempsas;
  put
    'data ' ds +(-1) '2;' /
    '  set ' ds ';' /    
    '  ' statements /
    'run;'
    ; 
run;
```

You can then start out by looking at the file (use the 'include tempsas' command in an edit window), submitting one datastep to see if everything goes well, and when you are sure that everything is fine, you put

```
%include tempsas;
```

in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments here (Thanks for your help guys!), I figured out a different solution (though changing my macro to accept named parameters worked too):

```
data test3;
    set test2;
    statement=tranwrd(statement,"=",'%nrstr(=)');
    call execute('%dummy('||strip(ds)||','||strip(statement)||')');
run;
```

Basically, I just altered the "code" to look like this:

> j1%nrstr(=)input(j,anydtdtm.); drop j; rename j1%nrstr(=)j; k1%nrstr(=)input(k,anydtdtm.); drop k; rename k1%nrstr(=)k; l1%nrstr(=)input(l,anydtdtm.); drop l; rename l1%nrstr(=)l;

I noticed that if I changed the macro to

```
%macro dummy(ds=,statements=);
data &ds.2;
  set &ds.;    
  &statements.
run;
%mend;
```

then this solution didn't work. It said "more positional parameters found than defined". Any ideas why?

Comment: The error message says what is wrong. You defined the macro parameters as named and then called it without the names.

Comment: To be fair that's one of the more confusing SAS error messages, given that you have to know what it means to understand what to fix :)

Comment: I will note that you certainly can `%nrstr` the equal sign, but you're wasting two characters there (`%str` will do the same thing if you are only quoting an equal sign) and for my $0.02 I find it more useful to `%nrstr` the entire string instead so that if you have a comma or similar it doesn't break.

Comment: @Joe But I do have commas in my statement, why does it still work?

Comment: @JonathanWilson I should be more specific, sorry; un-protected commas (parens and quotes protect them, ie, tell SAS to wait for a matching one to finish the parameter).  IE `%test(y,z);` fails, but `%test((y,z));` works, assuming `%test` takes one parameter.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks so much for taking the time to go through this with me!

Answer (score 0):

So rather pass statements to a macro, since I'm assuming you're also generating your statements to pass to the macro, I would only pass the variable names, original and desired and use an array.

```
%macro converter(var_in= , var_out=);
    data want;
      set data;
      array have(*) &var_in;
      array want(*) &var_out;

      do i=1 to dim(have);
         want(i)=input(have(i), anydtdtm.);
      end;
      drop &var_in;
     run;
 %mend;


 %converter(var_in= j1 k1 l1, var_out= j k l);
```

EDIT: Version 2 based on comments.To simplify the process, I rename the variables to temp1-temp{numvars} and then recode them into the variables desired. This was tested successfully.

```
%macro converter(var_in= j k l);
%let n_vars = %sysfunc(countw(&var_in));
    data want;
      set data (rename = (%do i=1 %to &n_vars;
                            %scan(&var_in, &i)=temp&i
                            %end;));
      array have(*) temp1-temp&n_vars.;
      array want(*) &var_in;

      do i=1 to dim(have);
         want(i)=input(have(i), anydtdtm.);
      end;
      drop temp1-temp&n_vars;
     run;
 %mend;

 %converter(var_in= j k l);
```

Comment: what about the rename portions?

Comment: The drop is there. I missed the rename to original vars ... I'll take a look to see how difficult to implement but doubt its hard.

Comment: Why? It would be a macro do loop?

Comment: What is it looping through?

Comment: The variable list.

Comment: Maybe you know about a macro function that I'm unaware of that parses out the variable list? I'm not familiar

Comment: %scan()? Theres lots of examples on here.

Comment: OK, I tried it out and it actually worked great! I'm definitely adding this to my go-to list. Thanks!