# How to change from character to numeric of many variables at a time in SAS?

Tags: sas

Say I have a dataset with 1000 variables without any naming pattern in SAS. Objective is to change the character variables to numeric. What might be an efficient way (using array, macro) to do it?

Thank you in advance,
Mamun

Comment: See the solution here, mine requires only the variables. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38755803/1919583

Comment: Sorry for asking. This question was answered here:  [link] (http://support.sas.com/kb/40/700.html)

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, you should enter it below as an answer and then mark it as accepted.  Don't just link to the page either, paraphrase it with a code example etc.

Comment: @RobertPenridge  Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered here: [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/40/700.html)